# draggable / moveable <div> horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make a div that is draggable / moveable horizontally, but not vertically?
I would prefer if this could be done without JQuery UI. JQuery is fine. Or vanilla JS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creating such a behavior yourself would be quite a bit of work. I would recommend using jquery ui :

http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/f7nNf/1/

Its a single line of code:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ axis: "x" });
```

And you don't event need to download the complete jquery ui. You can do a custom build with only draggable here : http://jqueryui.com/download/

Read more about draggable here: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

Comment: I didn't know one could do custom-builds of jQuery UI. The reason I'm not using jQuery UI is because of the size. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Great advice to use jquery ui as oppose to building it yourself - saved me a load of time (and most probably heartache)!

Comment: Original poster asked for plain JS answer. This should not be the accepted answer